# Angels Visiting Prophet Abraham on the Way to Prophet Lot

Tags: source-identification, prophet-ibrahim

During a most enjoyable speech about the story of Angel Gabriel ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9HuHcgv7E8)), Omar Suleiman talks about the three angels visiting Prophet Abraham on their way to annihilate the people of Prophet Lot. (Beginning at around [47m:55s](https://youtu.be/D9HuHcgv7E8?t=47m54s)) (In Quran the story is briefly mentioned more than once. The most detailed section (to my extremely limited knowledge) is **11:69-77**.)

Omar Suleiman gives a rather detailed account of the story. He barely mentions some sources, but I cannot find them. Where can I find it?

Further, at around [53m:40s](https://youtu.be/D9HuHcgv7E8?t=53m41s), Omar Suleiman mentions that the angels stated: *"Your Lord is Most Wise (al-Hakeem) and Most Knowledgeable (al-Aleem)."* What is interesting is that, as Omar Suleiman also points out, in Quran the order is always the other way round. (Omar Suleiman also gives the reasoning and wisdom behind this reversal of order.) Is this part also included in the sources that I am looking for?

Comment: The part about "The Most Wise and Most Knowledgeable" is from the Quran itself, [51:30](https://quran.com/51/30). You should mention exactly what specific statement you need a source for. There can be multiple sources for *qasas al anbiya*, including different verses in the Quran, sayings of the Sahabah and Israelite traditions etc.

Comment: For  a general direction, book of *Tafsir* and *Tarikh* mention such traditions. He refers to Qurtubi who wrote a Tafsir and other works. Ibn Kathir has authored a work called Al-Bidayah wa'an-Nihayah (The Beginning and the End) the first few volumes of which covers the stories of the Prophets.

Answer (score -2):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

When it comes to knowing the actual even that took place we have to look at the Quraan and ahadith. After searching I could not find any sources from the the Ahadith (Prophetic sayings) regarding the events that unfolded except for one:

> the Messenger of ALLAAH (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said: "Indeed, the honorable, the son of the honorable, the son of the honorable, the son of the honorable: Yusuf bin Ya'qub bin Ishaq bin Ibrahim." He said: "And if I were to have remained in the prison as long as Yusuf, then the messenger came, I would have accepted." Then he recited: When the messenger came to him, he said: "Return to your king and ask him: 'What happened to the women who cut their hands? (12:50)' **He said: "May Allah have mercy upon Lut, certainly he used to lean toward powerful support, since he said: "Would that I had strength to overpower you, or that I could betake myself to some powerful support (11:80)."** So Allah did not send a Prophet after him except among a high ranking family (Dhirwah) among his people." (Tirmidhi, in the chapter called "chapter on tafsirs")

**Note:** (Another chain) except that he said: "Allah did not send a Prophet after him except among a wealthy family (Tharwah) among his people."

---

With regards to the number of angels that came there is no specific number either so we leave it as just what shows in the verse below.

> And when Our messengers, [the angels], came to Lot, he was anguished for them and felt for them great discomfort1 and said, "This is a trying day." (Chapter 11 verse 77)

**When it comes to more information regarding the verses in Surah Hud (Chapter 11) revealed in the Quraan you can read more in the tafsir (commentary) of the Quraan by Ibn Kathir by clicking [here](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Hud)**

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted.